# Evaluate a model created using Tensorflow Object Detection API

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection-api, transfer-learning

I trained a model using Tensorflow object detection API for detecting swimming pools using satellite images. I used 'faster_rcnn_inception_v2_coco_2018_01_28' model for training. I generated a frozen inference graph (.pb). I want to evaluate the precision and recall of the model. Can someone tell me how I can do that, preferably without using pycocotools as I was facing some issues with that. Any suggestions are welcome :)

Answer (score 2):

From the Object Detection API you can run "eval.py" from "models/research/object_detection/legacy/".

Your have to define an evaluation metric in your config file (see the supported [evaluation protocols](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/evaluation_protocols.md))

For example:

```
   eval_config: {metrics_set: "coco_detection_metrics"}
```

The Pascal VOC e.g. then gives you the mean Average Precsion (mAP)